# Tensorboard - Profiling compute time - everything is a "unused substructure" in runtime statistics

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard

Tensorboard provides runtime statistics that allow profiling of memory consumption and compute time [(see Docu)](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz#runtime_statistics).
However in tensorflow v1.2.1 some of my ops were shown dashed & in orange as "unused substructure" and did not provide any information at all - no device, nor memory, nor compute time.

With the update to tensorflow v1.3 this even got worse. Now everything is a orange dashed "unused substructure" [image: tensorboard - missing stats, unused substructure]

I tried this on various bigger tensorflow projects that I need to optimize as well as on working colleagues PCs. 
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in tensorflow / tensorboard?

Here is an minimalistic example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

# create some dummy Ops for the graph
C1 = tf.constant(5)
C2 = tf.constant(3)
myOp = C1*C2 + tf.square(C2)
res = sess.run([myOp], options=run_options,run_metadata = run_metadata)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='tensorboard/profile_bug',graph=sess.graph)
print (res)

tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('tensorboard/timelineOfBug.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ctf)

writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata,"mySess")
writer.close()
sess.close()
```

Comment: Seems to be a tensorboard bug:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/298

Comment: With TF 1.2: If I select "Memory" in the "Color" radio buttons I see a list of "Devices included in stats:" checkboxes, one for my CPU, one for the GPU.  If I check the GPU box (which was unchecked by default), suddenly I can see nodes that are used (for all the different Color views, not just Memory).  Does that work for you?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Try unticking, and then reticking the GPU in the *Devices included in stats* in the panel to the left. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with some new versions of TF (seems like 1.2 and 1.3). Updating to 1.4 fixes it.